# mod_rewrite is not working, tried all possible ways

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

I swear am not able to get this, i read 10 tutorials but unable to make it work...I wanted pretty urls so my directory structure goes like this

```
localhost/my_website/home.php?page=dashboard
```

I have an `.htaccess` file in `my_website` folder with these rules

```
#Redirect To Default Login Page
DirectoryIndex login.php

#Block Directory Listing
IndexIgnore * 

# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ home.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But when I type this `http://localhost/my_website/home/dashboard` I actually do not get anything

What I get is

```
The requested URL /my_website/home/dashboard was not found on this server.
```

Comment: where is /page/ in your url?

Comment: @chumkiu `?page=dashboard`

Comment: should be here somewhere http://localhost/my_website/home/dashboard

Comment: @chumkiu doesn't work either, that's why am so damn confused, I don't see any reason why the hell this is not working

Comment: you must use this URL in browser http://localhost/my_website/page/some_url/

Comment: @chumkiu and if I type `http://localhost/my_website/home.php/dashboard` than I get `http://localhost/my_website/home.php/home.php?page=dashboard`

Comment: Firtst, be sure if .htaccess is enabled in apache conf (try to write invalid syntax in htaccess and see if it give you an internal server error)

Comment: ¿Are `home` and `dashboard` in `http://localhost/my_website/home/dashboard` dynamic or fixed strings?

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA `home.php` is the page, `page=dashboard` is the GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  my_website/%1.php?page=%2 [L,QSA]
```

It will map silently:

`http://localhost/my_website/anything1/anything2`

To:

`http://localhost/my_website/anything1.php?page=anything2`

I assumed `home` and `dashboard` in the question are variables (Can be anything).

Comment: @Yassine Houssni I know, but that name can be changed tomorrow and it's better than using a fixed string. Same happens with the value of page.

Comment: ahhh right right, that is indeed way better! thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you will need:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^my_website\/home\/([a-z0-9_-]+)?$ my_website/home.php?page=$1 [L]
```